# Flatten and tabularize a JSON in PANDAS/Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, flatten

**json_str** =
[
[
{
"AAAAA": "11111",
"BBBBB": "",
"CCCCC": "Listings",
"DDDDD": "Most_Critical",
"EEEEE": "task",
"FFFFF": null,
"GGGGG": 10.0,
"HHHHH": [],
"IIIII": [],
"JJJJJ": [
{
"KK": 42582,
"LL": 7005,
"MM": 5222,
"NN": " ",
"OO": "Tfl_Section",
"PP": "Its a date1",
"QQ": "Its a date2"
},
{
"KK": 42581,
"LL": 7005,
"MM": 5223,
"NN": " ",
"OO": "Order",
"PP": "date3",
"QQ": "date4"
},
{
"KK": 42580,
"LL": 7005,
"MM": 5224,
"NN": " ",
"OO": "Input_set",
"PP": "date5",
"QQ": "date6"
}
],
"RRRRR": []
},
{
"AAAAA": "222222",
"BBBBB": "",
"CCCCC": "Listings",
"DDDDD": "Most_Critical",
"EEEEE": "task",
"FFFFF": null,
"GGGGG": 10.0,
"HHHHH": [],
"IIIII": [],
"JJJJJ": [
{
"KK": 42565,
"LL": 7004,
"MM": 5225,
"NN": " ",
"OO": "Reference",
"PP": "date7",
"QQ": "date8"
},
{
"KK": 42564,
"LL": 7004,
"MM": 5226,
"NN": " ",
"OO": "Complexity_Level",
"PP": "date9",
"QQ": "date10"
},
],
"RRRRR": []
}
],
[]
]

That's my well redacted JSON. I want to tabularize it as follows

AAAAA BBBBB CCCCC DDDDD EEEEE FFFFF GGGGG HHHHH IIII JJJJJ

1  1111   ""    List

2   2222   ""    List2

and so on.

This is what I have tried till now
json_str = json.loads(df1.to_json(orient = 'records'))
df_flat = json_normalize(json_str)
print(df_flat)

This gives me an output as follows

0.AAAAA 0.BBBBB 0.CCCCC 0.DDDDD 0.EEEEE.......1.AAAAA, 1.BBBBB

I do no want 0.AAAAA or 1.AAAAA as header. I want one header/column for all AAAAA values.

Comment: That's not a valid JSON string

Comment: This is json string. I use this code to get that                                                 
                                                                                                                        
                         json_object = json.loads(json_str)

json_formatted_str = json.dumps(json_object, indent=1)

print(json_formatted_str)

Comment: Please present only a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you are trying to do. Your JSON string is very convoluted and contains "\" characters escaping double quotes. Replace them with `/` and format it for readability.